# vector<Class> or vector<unique_ptr<Class>> in this case?

Tags: c++, vector, unique-ptr

Let's say I have a class that looks like:

```
class Foo
{
    int sam;
    float fisher;
    double irvin;

    vector<Bar> lambert;
};
```

and I want to store instances of `Foo` into a vector

```
vector<Foo> foos;
```

since `lambert` can hold an undefined amount of `Bar`s, could object slicing happen or c++'s vector is pretty clever about it ?

Would it be better to use a vector of `unique_ptr` or do I worry too much about it ?

```
class Foo
{
    ...
    vector<unique_ptr<Bar>> lambert;
};
```

Thanks :) !

Comment: I see no vector slicing in your code.  All you have is a struct that contains a vector, and you're making a vector of these struct's.

Comment: In order to have slicing you need inheritance. Do you have inheritance in your code?

Comment: What do you mean by "slicing"? If you want instances of `Bar` in `Foo` then `std::vector<Bar>` is the way to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Object slicing happens when you store a derived value as its base.  It happens only to values.  Assuming you're always storing Bars, and not some derivative thereof, no slicing will occur.  `vector` stores its values elsewhere--it's not like keeping a statically sized array.

Comment: Ahhh Allright, yes, Bar is a "flat" class. I didn't get this well, now everything is clear. Thanks everyone.